# Change cursor type - Material UI Expansion Panel

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the MiU component "Expasion panel".
When the user hovers over the panel, the default behaviour is to set the cursor to `pointer`.
I modified it to display a `default` cursor instead.
However, it does not work.

My **component**:

```
<ExpansionPanel>
  <ExpansionPanelSummary
    className={classes.expasionPannelSummary}
  >
    ....rest of the code...
  </ExpansionPanelSummary
</ExpansionPanel>
```

My **styles.js**

```
expasionPannelSummary: {
    cursor: 'default',
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: 'default'
    },
    padding:them.spacing(1,3,1,3)
}
```

[image: CSS]

If I inspect the page, on the CSS says `cursor: "default"` but it is not.

Comment: In most browsers the `pointer` option is a hand, are you trying to display the default cursor? If so, you should look at the `default` option, [List cursor of options here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Comment: I am trying to display the `arrow`. I changed also `cursor: "pointer` to `cursor: default`, but nothing changes. I updated my initial question, specifing that I need the arrow (default).

Comment: Try `cursor: context-menu`

Comment: Regarding: `the CSS part it is written "default" but it is canceled out`, that means your CSS is being overwritten by some other CSS, which we can't really help with without seeing more of the code. Generally you can see where it's being overwritten by scrolling up in the dev tools until you find where that property is being set.

Comment: @DBS I fixed the CSS canceling out. It was a small bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue that you have is with the following css selector:

```
.MuiExpansionPanelSummary-root:hover:not(.Mui-disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

As you can see - it overrides your `cursor: default` that you are trying to apply.

To handle this you can use the `createMuiTheme` and set the following:

```
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiExpansionPanelSummary: {
      root: {
        "&:hover:not(.Mui-disabled)": {
          cursor: "default"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/expansion-cursor-change-ywqq5?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way material-ui manages styles. Try with the following:

```
<ExpansionPanel>
  <ExpansionPanelSummary
    classes={{root: classes.expasionPannelSummary}}
  >
    ....rest of the code...
  </ExpansionPanelSummary
</ExpansionPanel>
```

Check the [API for the component](https://material-ui.com/es/api/expansion-panel-summary/) and [how to override the styles in material-ui](https://material-ui.com/es/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes).

Comment: If I do the following, in the inspector I have two CSS. One with `pointer` and one with `default`. The one with default is canceled out.

Comment: That's weird, it's supposed to work without an override (!important), did you try with it?

Comment: With `!important` works also without changing my initial code. Thanks